# bcp сохранить файл на локальной машине

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bcp

Создал приложение на C# которое формирует XML файлы (для этого использовал bcp.exe). Вот пример кода

```
command.CommandText = "EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp.exe \"select * from Primer.dbo.TempLot 
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT, Elements\"  queryout C:\\new\\outxml1.XML -w -r -T'";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Проблема в том что когда я запускаю приложение на локальной машине, то сформированный XML файл сохраняется на сервере (где установлен MS SQL), можно ли его сохранить на локальной машине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выполняете bcp.exe на той машине, где установлен SQL Server. Так что есть всего несколько вариантов на выбор:

- выполнять bcp.exe на той же машине, на которой вы выполняете приложение (запускать его через `Process.Start()`, указывая удаленный сервер)
- расшарить папку `C:\new` на удаленном сервере и переписывать оттуда файл
- расшарить папку на локальной машине, отдавать ее сетевой путь как параметр для bcp вместо `C:\new`